# Display diagram in mxGraph with the help of xml

Tags: javascript, angular, mxgraph

Diagram (with xml) is not show exactly the same diagram which I have created with the help of mxGraph tool, I am creating diagram with below code:

I have created diagram with mxGraph tool as below:

[image]

I saved xml in localstorage as of now, and from xml I did below code to display the diagram in one of my div container as shown below:

```
let xml = '<mxGraphModel dx="963" dy="318" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="850" pageHeight="1100"><root><mxCell id="0"/><mxCell id="1" parent="0"/><mxCell id="2" value="" style="shape=mxgraph.basic.t2;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;fillColor=#ffffff;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=2" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="30" y="30" width="79" height="267" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="3" value="Actor" style="shape=umlActor;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;labelBackgroundColor=#ffffff;verticalAlign=top;html=1;outlineConnect=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="470" y="80" width="140" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="4" value="" style="shape=internalStorage;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="300" y="40" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="5" value="" style="ellipse;shape=cloud;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="220" y="230" width="120" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell></root></mxGraphModel>';
let doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
let codec = new mxCodec(doc);
codec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
let elt = doc.documentElement.firstChild;
let cells = [];
while (elt != null)
{
    let cell = codec.decode(elt)
    if(cell != undefined){
        if(cell.id != undefined && cell.parent != undefined && (cell.id == cell.parent)){
            elt = elt.nextSibling;
            continue;
        }
        cells.push(cell);
    }
    elt = elt.nextSibling;
}
graph.addCells(cells);
```

**Below ouput is ganerated from above code**:

[image]

So issue is I want to display exact the same diagram which I have created, but it is showing only shapes of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The core mxGraph library doesn't understand the shape style for the 3 incorrect shapes. Those are defined in the graph for [GraphEditor](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html). For example, see the [umlActor](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph2/blob/master/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/js/Shapes.js#L1547).

Comment: Thanks @thomas for reply, yeah true but If I want to acheive this shapes then how can we acheive this? any solution or should I use some diffrent tool for it?